# selendroid driver will get URL or not

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selendroid

I want to perform Webpage UI testing across browsers in Android Device using Selenium.
So, I am using "Selendroid" to open the browser app(Firefox and Opera) unlike Chrome browser opened with chrome driver and I am getting the driver object for the corresponding app, with the driver object I need to perform several actions on the webpage like, open the URL, getting element locations/positions, clicking the object, verifying the object attributes, etc.,

But, I am getting the following problems,

1. Firefox app is not started, because it is showing the following exception always,

I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to{}-->http://localhost:8080: The target server failed to respond)

2. Opera app is started, but the driver object that I got after this is not able to open the URL (driver.getURL("//myURL");). It is throwing following exception,

   ```
   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: CATCH_ALL: io.selendroid.server.common.exceptions.SelendroidException: Unrecognized scheme in URI: http://www.google.com
   at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidNativeDriver.get(SelendroidNativeDriver.java:103)
   at io.selendroid.server.model.DefaultSelendroidDriver.get(DefaultSelendroidDriver.java:538)
   at io.selendroid.server.handler.OpenUrl.safeHandle(OpenUrl.java:38)
   at io.selendroid.server.handler.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:87)
   at io.selendroid.server.AndroidServlet.handleRequest(AndroidServlet.java:264)
   at io.selendroid.server.common.BaseServlet.handleHttpRequest(BaseServlet.java:67)
   at io.selendroid.server.common.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:53)
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
   at io.netty.handler.traffic.AbstractTrafficShapingHandler.channelRead(AbstractTrafficShapingHandler.java:223)
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
   at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
   at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:163)
   at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:148)
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
   at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:125)
   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:430)
   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:384)
   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
   at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
   at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

   Command duration or timeout: 53 milliseconds
   Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
   System info: host: 'AccentureInteractives-MacBook.local', ip: '10.218.112.47', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.5', java.version: '1.6.0_65'
   Session ID: 89cf35cf-8933-a71e-f0be-91abe1dbc619
   Driver info: io.selendroid.client.SelendroidDriver
   Capabilities [{automationName=selendroid, platform=ANY, platformName=android, browserName=selendroid, emulator=false, aut=com.opera.browser:30.0.1856.92967}]
   ```

My device(s) details,

Mac book(for connecting my android device) version: 10.8.5

Android Device: Samsung S3

Android Version: 4.1.2

Someone, help me here.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have any programming related questions?

Comment: Tell me any way to open firefox and opera browsers in an android device and i have to get driver object for that browser. I am unsuccessful in using with "RemoteWebDriver" and "Selendroid Driver", so please give me some idea/approach to do it.

Comment: You don't have any programming related questions?

Comment: http://selendroid.io/mobileWeb.html#java use this one as reference. It will be good if you can describe code flow here to understand your problem